# Как сохранить массив bool или int?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вопрос заключается в том, что мне нужно сохранить массив либо типа bool, либо типа int, но через PlayerPrefs не получается, но скорее всего я делаю что-то не то. Как можно это сделать ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Сериализуйте в JSON и сохраните как строку.

Comment: Вы хоть напишите, что-же вы делаете, а мы уж скажем что с этим не так.